# Can anyone help me with my JAVA Swing code?

Tags: java, jframe

It's been 3 days since I encounter this problem and still can't find a better solution:

```java
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        labelA.setForeground(Color.black);
        labelB.setForeground(Color.black);
        jLabel3.setForeground(Color.black);
        int check=0;
        try {
            check = search(textUserId.getText(),
                textFName.getText());
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // Logger.getLogger(frameRegister.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(frameRegister.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        if(check==1){
            try {
                if(textPassword.getText() == null ?
                    "" == null : textPassword.getText().equals("")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "First Name and Last must contain value","System Message",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    textUserAddress.setText(null);
                    textUserId.setText(null);
                    textFName.setText(null);
                    textLName.setText(null);
                    textAge.setText(null);
                    textUBirth.setText(null);
                    textContactNum.setText(null);
                    textPassword.setText(null);
                    textEmailAdd.setText(null);
                    textMaritalStatus.setText(null);
                    textUserOccupation.setText(null);
                    jLabel3.setForeground(Color.red);
                }
                if((textUserId.getText() == null ? "" == null :
                    textUserId.getText().equals("")) ||
                (textFName.getText() == null ? "" == null :
                    textFName.getText().equals(""))){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "ID and Name is Required","System Message",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                labelB.setForeground(Color.red);
                labelA.setForeground(Color.red);
            }
            else{
                st.executeUpdate("Insert into info("
                    + "id,firstname,lastname,age,dateofbirth,marital_status,address,occupation,contact_no,email_add,"
                    + "password" + ") VALUES ('"
                    + textUserId.getText() + "','"
                    + textFName.getText() + "','"
                    + textLName.getText() + "','"
                    + textAge.getText() + "','"
                    + textUBirth.getText() + "','"
                    + textMaritalStatus.getText() + "','"
                    + textUserAddress.getText() + "','"
                    + textUserOccupation.getText() + "','"
                    + textContactNum.getText() + "','"
                    + textPassword.getText() + "')");
   

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Created",
                    "System Message",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                frameMain.this.setVisible(false);
                textUserId.setText("");
                frameMain fm= new frameMain();
                fm.show();
               
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // Logger.getLogger(frameMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Record Already Exist","System Message",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            textUserAddress.setText(null);
            textUserId.setText(null);
            textFName.setText(null);
            textLName.setText(null);
            textAge.setText(null);
            textUBirth.setText(null);
            textContactNum.setText(null);
            textLName.setText(null);
            textPassword.setText(null);
            textMaritalStatus.setText(null);
            textUserOccupation.setText(null);
            textEmailAdd.setText(null);

        }

        }
    }
```

My problem is after clicking the SAVED button it will appear "Record Already Exist" when, in fact, it doesn't.

I am expecting that I will get a negative and positive impact but I hope someone will help me.

Comment: You can improve error handling and debug your code. By printing the exception details (using `ex.printStackTrace()`), you can get more info about the errors you're encountering.

Comment: Yes, swallowing exceptions like this is not "friendly" or improving user experience, it's just annoying.  At least while you're still developing anyway.  Log or print the error.

Comment: Use a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for the SQL. It will do the SQL formatting for you.

Comment: [Poor title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Please edit so the question title is about the actual issue. Please consider other advice in [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .

Comment: This reads like a "Howto SQL injection".